# Find the title of a dynamically-loaded HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am experimenting with dynamically-loading content (e.g. when the user clicks the link, the content is loaded in the background instead of the whole page refreshing).

I can't figure out how to get the title from the DOM Elements returned by [`jQuery.parseHTML`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/).  The API documentation states that it "uses a native DOM element creation function to convert the string to a set of DOM elements, which can then be inserted into the document."

The following code does not get the "title" node from the set. When I look at the list in the chrome debugger console, I see the list, formatted with each element in the array appearing like `[#: type]` (e.g. `[1: title]` as the title node is the second element in this example). I can see it there, and click on it in the debugger, but can't figure out how to access it in a logical way from my code.

Can someone please help?

```
$('#mainContent').load(url, function (response, status) {
        if (status != "success") {
            $('#mainContent').hide();
            $('.notFound').show();

            document.title = getTitle("Page Not Found");
        }
        else {
            var title = jQuery.parseHTML(response)['title'].innerText;
            title = getTitle(title); //does some validation on the input (e.g. not blank, etc).
            document.title = title;
            $('#mainContent').show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: what does `console.log($.parseHTML(response));` print? Try `$.parseHTML(response).find('title');`

Comment: I've tried a `.find('title')` and it gave an error about 'find' not being defined for arrays of DOM elements.

Comment: Console out shows: [text, text, link, text, title, text, comment, text, text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work (you may have to change TITLE to title):

```
$.each( jQuery.parseHTML(response), function( i, el ) {
  if(el.nodeName === "TITLE") {
    title = $(el).html();
    return false; // break out of the each loop
  }
});
```

Edit: small change should make it a little quicker for large amounts of DOM nodes

Comment: Thanks, I was just writing up a loop to do it. This looks nicer than what I've got.

Comment: It seems slow (I can perceive the delay in title changing), but it does work.